# Intellij Scala SBT Plugin -Take SBT Offline

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, ivy, intellij-plugin

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 version. When I add dependency in build.sbt , it connects to the internet and downloads all the required jar files in ~.ivy2/cache folder. But next time when I disconnect the laptop from internet and create a new project and add the same dependency it is still attempting to connect to the internet and its failing, It is not using the ~.ivy2/cache folder jars. Similar issue was present  specifying sbt ofline:true, but this was only when we write in command line. How to do the same setting in IntelliJ SBT ?. In IntelliJ i have used scala plugin

Comment: This problem will be present only when SBT is used as part of plugin. I haven't tested it but that must be the problem. when we use SBT installed in the OS and use command line to build the jar this can be fixed by using sbt:offline. This was a fix given by SBT but this fix is yet to be added in the plugin.Checked this when this question was posted